# Multiple PivotTables in Dash plotly python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to generate n pivot tables in Python Dash Plotly. n is the user input. Or add a button 'add pivot table' which generates a pivot table after each click. I tried it this way:

```
@app.callback(Output("pivottable_div", "children"), [Input("button", "n_clicks")])
def refresh_pivottable(n_clicks):
    for i in range(n_clicks):
        print(n_clicks)
        return [
            html.Div(str(n_clicks)),
            dash_pivottable.PivotTable(data=[["a"], [n_clicks]], cols=["a"])
            if n_clicks % 2 == 1
            else "a",
        ]
```

But the above code is not working. Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally implemented the logic to generate multiple pivot table on the dashboard. Below code implements that

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.title = 'My Dash example'

app.layout = html.Div([
    
    html.Button('Add Pivot Table', id='click', n_clicks=0),
    
    dash_pivottable.PivotTable(
        id='table',
        data=[list(covid_19_data_top_10.columns)] + covid_19_data_top_10.values.tolist(),
        cols=['Month'],
        rows=['Country'],
        rowOrder="key_a_to_z",
        rendererName="Grouped Column Chart",
        aggregatorName="Average",
        vals=["Confirmed"],
    ),
    
    
    
    
    html.Div(
        id='output'
    )
])


@app.callback(Output('output', 'children'),
              [Input('table', 'cols'),
               Input('table', 'rows'),
               Input('table', 'rowOrder'),
               Input('table', 'colOrder'),
               Input('table', 'aggregatorName'),
               Input('table', 'rendererName'),
              Input('click', 'n_clicks')])
def display_props(cols, rows, row_order, col_order, aggregator, renderer, n_clicks):
    return [
        dash_pivottable.PivotTable(
        id='table'+str(id),
        data=[list(covid_19_data_top_10.columns)] + covid_19_data_top_10.values.tolist(),
        cols=['Month'],
        colOrder="key_a_to_z",
        rows=['Country'],
        rowOrder="key_a_to_z",
        rendererName="Grouped Column Chart",
        aggregatorName="Average",
        vals=["Confirmed"],
    ) for id in range(n_clicks)
    ]
```

Dashboard:
[image]
[image]